# Что не так с урл? Не работает @RequestMapping() над контроллером

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url, tomcat

Приложение поддерживает spring mvc+hibernate+maven+tomcat.
Есть один контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerBookmarks {
    private BookmarksService bookmarksService;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerBookmarks.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bookmarksService")
    public void setBookmarksService(BookmarksService bookmarksService) {
        this.bookmarksService = bookmarksService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bookmarks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listBookmarks(Model model) {
        logger.info("Вызван: listBookmarks");
        model.addAttribute("bookmark", new Bookmarks());
        model.addAttribute("bookmarks", bookmarksService.listBookmarks());
        return "bookmarks";
    }
```

И есть одна jsp, имя ей - `bookmarks`
Вот структура проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Приложение деплоится в tomcat с контекстом - `/`.
- Диспетчер-сервлет спринга обрабатывает любые запросы по адресу - `/`.

  Если я так запускаю приложение, то все работает нормально, url такой - `localhost:8080/bookmarks`. Но я хочу написать над контроллером `@RequestMapping("/bm")`. Когда я это делаю и обращаюсь по адресу - `localhost:8080/bm/bookmarks`. Я не получаю свою jsp
  Вот что мне пишет в ошибке - Message - /bm/WEB-INF/view/bookmarks.jsp. Код ошибки 404. Где я мог что-то не указать или пропустил, подскажите пожалуйста, хотя бы примерно?

---

Вот так я хочу сделать, написал реквест маппинги и когда в браузере пишу такой урл - `localhost:8080/bm/bookmarks`. Мне выдает 404 и message,который выше я написал. А должен обработать listBookmarks и вернуть нужную jsp. Я так понимаю, вот это сообщение - `Message - /bm/WEB-INF/view/bookmarks.jsp` строится из того, что я написал `@RequestMapping("/bm")` над контроллером и то, что резолвер находит в папке с view. Но почему он строит такой путь и как это исправить не получается разобраться

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bm")
public class ControllerBookmarks {
    private BookmarksService bookmarksService;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerBookmarks.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bookmarksService")
    public void setBookmarksService(BookmarksService bookmarksService) {
        this.bookmarksService = bookmarksService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bookmarks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listBookmarks(Model model) {
        logger.info("Вызван: listBookmarks");
        model.addAttribute("bookmark", new Bookmarks());
        model.addAttribute("bookmarks", bookmarksService.listBookmarks());
        return "bookmarks";
    }
```

Comment: ну так и напишите @RequestMapping(value = "/bm/bookmarks", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: Положи jsp в папку с ресурсами.

Comment: @ermak0ff, а зачем это писать над методом, если я эту часть `/bm` хочу написать над контроллером, эта часть урл же подставляется под каждый метод. Я добавлю щас в конец вопроса код контроллера, как я пишу и у меня не работает этот вариант.

Comment: @Roman C, как тогда указать резолверу, который отображает эти jsp путь, к папке, которая находится за web-папкой

Comment: Попробовал скомбинировать 2а `@RequestMapping` в своем проекте, работает, как вы предполагали. Ищете ошибку в другом месте. Попробуйте запустить отладчик и выяснить, где происходит ошибка и какое пробрасывается исключение.

Comment: Сначала надо показать где тут резолвер и почему он не работает, ну также попытки его заработать

Comment: @KrychunIvan, так я знаю где ошибка происходит. У меня есть две jsp страницы, первая - `welcom.jsp` она сразу открывается когда приходит запрос на адерс - `localhost:8080/`. Вот она нормально открылась, и с нее у меня ссылка на вторую - `<a href="<c:url value = "/bm/bookmarks"/>" target="_self">BOOKMARKS</a>`, вот когда по ссылке перехожу, получаю - ошибку 404 `Message - /bm/WEB-INF/view/bookmarks.jsp`. Самое странное, в адресной строке у меня правильный путь - `localhost:8080/bm/bookmarks`, но страницы, увы, не отображается, если убрать на контроллером реквест маппинг, то все нормально..

Comment: Из `message` видно, что резолвер, пытается искать эту jsp страницу по вот такому пути - `/bm/WEB-INF/view/bookmarks.jsp`, но она лежит по такому -  `/bm/WEB-INF/view/bookmarks.jsp`. Почему перед WEB-INF этот кусок появляется я вообще понятия не имею

Comment: @MaksOhotnikov ну так всё ясно `<a href="<c:url value = "/bm/bookmarks"/>" target="_self">BOOKMARKS</a>` -> `<a href="/bm/bookmarks">BOOKMARKS</a>`

Comment: @KrychunIvan, нет, тоже самое. Так если уберу реквест над контроллером, ссылка-то работает

Comment: @MaksOhotnikov jstl [url](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm) - команда для форматирования URL, вам же необходимо простое перенаправление на другой адрес, для чего `html` тег `a`  и используют, изменив обращение вы ну ни как не получите ту же ошибку.

Comment: @KrychunIvan, вот - https://github.com/Albu-querque/Bookmarks.git, можете сами посмотреть

Comment: Может я неправильно как то томкэт настроил.. использую томкэт 9. ApplicationContext - `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в настройках viewResolver'а. Префикс должен начинаться с /. 
Если префикс не начинается с /, то путь к шаблону считается относительным и определяется относительно запрашиваемого пути, откуда берётся /bm.
Правильный вариант настройки viewResolver'а:

```
<bean id="resolver" сlass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/resources/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Да, все заработало, я вообще не обратил внимания на это. Пробовал 100500 раз разные варианты и постоянно натыкалсы на этот непонятный для меня путь - `/bm/WEB-INF/view/bookmarks.jsp`. Но теперь стало ясно почему `/bm` становится перед `/WEB-INF`. Большое спасибо.